# CiviCRM and Caldera Forms

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, custom-fields, forms

I have a general question really.

I am working with a client who is using CiviCRM. He has a membership joining page, donation pages, main donation and sub donations ie. £4, £6, £10 as well as a contact form. We have had problems using the CRM forms on the website so I am looking at using contact form 7. I understand that contact form 7 has an integration with the CiviCRM.

Can I build the forms with contact form 7 which would include checkboxes, dropdowns, text fields and will all this data go to the CiviCRM, and will it still work if I make multiple forms, will they all send data to the CRM?

Answer (score 1):

The Contact Form 7 integration basically takes all fields from the form and sends the data to CiviCRM. So basically you have 2 options when creating forms:

1. Use one of the standard CiviCRM API calls, and make sure the fields on your form are named as required by the API call
2. Develop an extension with your own API calls and use those (with the field names) on your form.